# Does ps6spy support currentSchema in postgresql url parameter?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, p6spy

I use p6spy-3.8.6 and postgresql-42.2.9.jre7 modules in WildFly 10 to define datasource. 
In standalone.xml if I use it's

```
I ok - <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/migrazione?currentSchema=pidea</connection-url>

II ko - <connection-url>jdbc:p6spy:postgresql://localhost:5432/migrazione?currentSchema=pidea</connection-url>
```

In the II case I have this exception:

java.sql.SQLException: Unable to find a driver that accepts jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/migrazione?currentSchema=pidea
    at com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver.findPassthru(P6SpyDriver.java:131)

Does p6spy support **currentSchema** in postgres jdbc url connection? 
Is there a workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed in module.xml ( module name="org.postgresql" ) of p6spy module:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.p6spy">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="p6spy-3.8.6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="org.postgresql"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```